# menubutton event not working for me

Tags: cordova

I using of the Cordova for build an Android application . I want to when the menu button was touched, a div tag appear.
I used of the `menubutton` event but this not working. I test my application on emulator and check via android monitor discover errors. you can see the logs in bellow :

```
 - 06-12 07:08:08.615: W/audio_hw_primary(108): out_write() limiting sleep time 44149 to 23219
 - 06-12 07:08:08.635: W/EGL_emulation(3215): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
 - 06-12 07:08:08.639: W/audio_hw_primary(108): out_write() limiting sleep time 55759 to 23219
 - 06-12 07:08:08.659: W/audio_hw_primary(108): out_write() limiting sleep time 47369 to 23219
 - 06-12 07:08:08.687: W/audio_hw_primary(108): out_write() limiting sleep time 28979 to 23219
 - 06-12 07:08:08.731: W/audio_hw_primary(108): out_write() limiting sleep time 31178 to 23219
```

My whole index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery_mobile_1_4_5/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery_mobile_1_4_5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<header id="header" data-role="header">
    <img src="img/logo.png">
</header>
<section data-role="page" id="home-page">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="pages-buttons">
            <a href="#first-home" class="page-button center-button">فهرست محتوا</a>
            <a href="#about-book" class="page-button center-button">درباره کتاب</a>
            <a href="#about-me" class="page-button center-button">درباره ما</a>
            <a href="#setting" class="page-button center-button">تنظیمات</a>
            <a href="" class="exit-from-app page-button center-button">خروج از برنامه</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section data-position="fixed" data-role="page" id="about-me">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="align-center">

        </div>

    </div>
</section>
<section data-position="fixed" data-role="page" id="about-book">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h2 class="post-title">درباره کتاب</h2>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="img/book.jpg"><br>
    </div>
</section>
<section data-position="fixed" data-role="page" id="first-home">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h2 class="post-title">فهرست مطالب</h2>

        <div id="links">

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section data-role="page" id="setting">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h2 class="post-title">تنظیمات</h2>
        <div id="content" style="direction: ltr">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="rtl" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
                <legend class="rtl label">نوع فونت </legend>
                <input type="radio" name="font-family" id="font-yekan" value="yekan" checked>
                <label style="font-family: yekan !important;" for="font-yekan">یکان</label>
                <input type="radio" name="font-family" id="font-nazanin" value="nazanin">
                <label style="font-family: nazanin !important;" for="font-nazanin">نازنین</label>
                <input type="radio" name="font-family" id="font-mitra" value="mitra">
                <label style="font-family: mitra !important;" for="font-mitra">میترا</label>
                <input type="radio" name="font-family" id="font-terafik" value="terafik">
                <label style="font-family: terafik !important;" for="font-terafik">ترافیک</label>
            </fieldset>
            <br>
            <label class="rtl label" for="font-size">اندازه فونت</label>
            <input type="range" name="slider-fill-mini" id="font-size" value="19" min="8" max="30" data-mini="true" data-highlight="true" data-theme="a" data-track-theme="d">
            <br>
            <a data-mini="true"  data-inline="true" id="cancel-setting" data-rel="back" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Cancel</a>
            <input type="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="save-setting" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-icon="check" value="Save">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<footer id="footer" data-role="footer">
    <div id="back-buttons" class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a align-center">
            <a class="icon no-link" data-rel="back" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b align-center">
            <a class="icon no-link" href="#home-page"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<div class="menu-bar">
    <div class="menu-grid ui-grid-c">
        <div class="menu-block ui-block-a">
            <a href="#setting" class="exit-from-app ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-top">خروج</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-block ui-block-b">
            <a href="#setting" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-top">تنظیمات</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-block ui-block-c">
            <a href="#first-home" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-top">فهرست مطالب</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-block ui-block-d">
            <a href="#home-page" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-top">صفحه اول</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_mobile_1_4_5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="nice_scroll/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shia.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And shia.js :

```
$(document).ready(onLoad);
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady(){
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    if (typeof window.localStorage.getItem('firstTime') === 'undefined' || window.localStorage.getItem('firstTime') == null)
    {
        alert('first run');
        db.transaction(populateDB);
        window.localStorage.setItem('firstTime', 0);
    }

    $("[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']").toolbar();
    $('body').niceScroll();

    $(document).on("pageshow",function(event){
        db.transaction(applySetting);
        if($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == 'home-page')
            $('#back-buttons').hide();
        else
            $('#back-buttons').show();
    });

    $('.exit-from-app').click(exitFromApp);
    $('#save-setting').click(function(){
        db.transaction(settingQuery);
        alert('تنظیمات با موفقیت اعمال شد');
    })

    document.addEventListener("menubutton", menubutton, false);

    db.transaction(applySetting);
}

function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS setting');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS setting (title text, value text)');
    tx.executeSql('insert into setting(title, value) values("font_family", "nazanin")');
    tx.executeSql('insert into setting(title, value) values("font_size", "19")');
    alert('table created');
    return true;
}

function errorCB(tx, err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}

function settingQuery(tx)
{
    var font_family = $('input[name="font-family"]:checked').val();
    var font_size = $('#font-size').val();
    tx.executeSql('delete from setting where 1');
    tx.executeSql('insert into setting(title, value) values("font_family", "' + font_family + '")');
    tx.executeSql('insert into setting(title, value) values("font_size", "' + font_size + '")');
}
function applySetting(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('select * from setting where title = "font_family"', [], function(tx, results){
        if(results.rows.length)
        {
            alert(results.rows[0].value);
            $('.content').css('font-family', results.rows[0].value);
            if($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == 'setting')
            {
                $('input[name="font-family"]').prop( "checked", false ).checkboxradio( "refresh" );
                $('input#font-' + results.rows[0].value).prop( "checked", true).checkboxradio( "refresh" );
            }
        }
    });

    tx.executeSql('select * from setting where title = "font_size"', [], function(tx, results){
        if(results.rows.length)
        {
            $('.content').css('font-size', results.rows[0].value + 'px');
            if($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == 'setting')
            {
                $('#font-size').val( results.rows[0].value);
            }
        }
    });
}
function menubutton(){
    $('.menu-bar').toggle();
}

function exitFromApp()
{
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the menu button
//
function onMenuKeyDown() {
    // add simple testing function
    alert('menu button pressed');
    $('.menu-bar').toggle();
}
```

and trigger the onLoad button on your HTML like so :

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```